# Bytecode - public and private attributes differences

Tags: java, private, bytecode, public

What is the difference in bytecode between public attribute and private one with simple getter/setter in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With public field you have:

```
aload_0
iconst_1
putfield        #1; //Field public
return
```

With private + set/get:

```
aload_0
iconst_1
putfield        #1; //Field private
return

public int getA();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   getfield        #1; //Field private
   4:   ireturn

public void setA(int);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   iload_1
   2:   putfield        #1; //Field private
   5:   return
```

So from the performance point of view private + set/get gives just unnecessary overhead. But it have an architecture profits and should be used by some conventions like JavaBeans.

Comment: What tool do you use to view the instructions?

Comment: javap -c <class file name without .class extension>

Comment: A JIT will, with high likelihood, inline uses of the setter/getter.

Comment: True, but you can never be sure, as there are many JVMs vendors and many modes of running java classes.

Comment: Please, please, don't expose public non-final fields.  Effective Java item 14 explains why.  (Also, I will weep if you expose public non-final fields.)